# How to programatically replace integer comparisons with boolean comparisons on a string?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm converting a C++ app to C#, and in many places it used `AnsiCompare` to compare two strings. This returns an integer, so all over the code there are things like this:

```
if (str.AnsiCompare("value") == 0 || str2.AnsiCompare("val") != 0)
```

I just did a Find and Replace on `AnsiCompare` to switch it with `Equals`, but since you can't implicitly convert a `bool` to an `int` in C# I have to manually go through and remove all comparisons to 0.

Instead, I'm trying to write an application that'll go through and parse out line by line like so:

```
List<int> lineIndices = new List<int>();
int lineIndex = 0;

foreach(var line in lines)
{
    int index = line.IndexOf("Equals(\"");

    if (index > 0)
        lineIndices.Add(lineIndex)
}

for (int i = lineIndices.Count; i >= 0; i--)
{
    lines[lineIndices[i]].Replace(" == 0", String.Empty);
}
```

I haven't actually tested it yet, but the basic idea is to loop over each line, see if it calls "Equals" and add that line number to a list of line numbers. Then loop back through (not sure if I actually need to do it in reverse, but I guess it doesn't matter) and replace all 'equal to zero' comparisons with an empty `string`. Since it `Equals` returns a `bool`, this is fairly simple. However, when comparing to `!= 0`, I don't know how I could find the beginning of the segment of code to prefix an exclamation point.

I know there is `String.IndexOf(string, int32, int32)` to search for a value starting at a given location and up to a certain number of positions to check but I kind of need the *opposite* of that. Start at a location and check backwards for a space, then replace that space with a space + exclamation point?

I suppose I could just start at the beginning and use `LastIndexOf` to find the last space before the index of `"Equals"`, but this doesn't account for situations that don't have a space, such as `if (someStr.Equals("val") != 0)`. Then I'd get the space before the `(`.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Why not try using regex in Find and replace? Ref - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2k3te2cs.aspx

Comment: While it'd certainly cut down on my code to determine which lines to add to my list, I'm not sure how that'd help me determine where to insert the `!`?

Comment: Make two separate searches, with `==` and `!=`.

Answer (score 2):

The Visual Studio 'Find and Replace' tool with 'Use Regular Expressions' on is perfect for such tasks.

For example to replace every `stringVariable.AnsiCompare(stringLiteral) == 0` with `stringVariable == stringLiteral` you can use the following regular expression:

```
(?<str>[a-zA-Z0-9]*)\.AnsiCompare\((?<compareWith>"[^"]*")\) == 0
```

And replace with

```
${str} == ${compareWith}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would replace `str.AnsiCompare("value")` to `string.Compare(str, "value")` by using RegEx

Comment: This doesn't really solve the problem of him wanting it to be a boolean, hence moving to `Equals`.

Comment: @vaibhav-chaurasiya: Do not change the code/content of the answer while editing, which could change and/or invalidate the very intent of the author. I've rolled back your edit.

Comment: @ Abhitalks : Yes i have make changes in code also.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could write an extension method and simply add using instead of all the replacements

```
public static int AnsiComapre(this string x, string y)
{
    return String.Compare(x, y);
}
```